# Can't install puppeteer on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am having a trouble in installing Puppeteer on Windows 10, when I type `npm i puppeteer` and Enter, after a while install, I got those error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\VSCode\Files\NodeJS\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command D:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! node:events:505
npm ERR!       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: A81A0000:error:0A000119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:614:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket._emitTLSError (node:_tls_wrap:901:10)
npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.onerror (node:_tls_wrap:433:11) {
npm ERR!   library: 'SSL routines',
npm ERR!   reason: 'decryption failed or bad record mac',
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Node.js v18.0.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-04T09_42_58_161Z-debug-0.log
```

I have set the PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_HOST to storage.googleapis.com but It's not help me. Can someone help me install it?

Comment: what are your Node.js version and the puppeteer version you try to install? (the latter is I suppose 13.7.0; is the Node v18?)

Answer (score 0):

**First**
you need to install puppeteer with this command:

> npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer

**Second**
download chrome from this [link](https://registry.npmmirror.com/binary.html?path=chrome-for-testing/)
choose the version that your system asks for, in my case *chrome v  115.0.5790.102* it will downloaded as a zip file so you need to extract it and place it on your project then take chrome application path and assign it to puppeteer by this code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: 'new',
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        executablePath: "C:/Users/Rjab/IdeaProjects/scraping-airbnb/chrome-win64/chrome"
    });
```